# LyX: Removing indentation from a table

Tags: tables, indentation, width

I want to make a table that has terms on the left side with `.25\textwidth` and descriptions on the right side with `.75\textwidth` Like

```
Name:                    asdjoia
Position:                astronaut
...:                     sadas
```

With the widths of the columns set, the table tends to be a bit on the right side of the paper though.
I tried inserting a LaTeX argument for the table: `@{}ll@{}`, which indeed removes the indentation, but leaves me without the permanent width of the left side.

The source of the table looks like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}>{\raggedright}p{0.25\textwidth}>{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth}}
Name: & asdjoia\tabularnewline
Position: & astronaut\tabularnewline
...: & sadas\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

And the related preamble code set to

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have removed the outer padding with `@{}` but you still have padding on the inner cell borders totalling `2\tabcolsep` You may also have a paragraph indentation (depending on the code you didn't show)  so

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                      >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr0.75\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}}
```