# Do not indent a tabular

Tags: tables

In the following minimal example, the tabular seems to be indented, unless I misunderstand (for example, maybe left-aligned does not do what I think?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text

\vspace{.2cm}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
text in row 1, col 1& text in row 1, col 2\tabularnewline
text in row 2, col 1& text in row 2, col 2
\end{tabular}

\noindent Some text afterward

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:
[image]

I have found the following related posts but the solutions do not work for me:

[Little indentation despite \noindent after tabu custom-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128484/little-indentation-despite-noindent-after-tabu-custom-environment)

[LyX: Removing indentation from a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113420/lyx-removing-indentation-from-a-table)

[Indentation after '\tabular' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123229/indentation-after-tabular-environments)

I've tried to add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` but that does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is as a result of the `\tabcolsep` space inserted around every column. Using a column specification with `@{}` will remove the column separation at that specific column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
  text in row 1, col 1 & text in row 1, col 2 \\
  text in row 2, col 1 & text in row 2, col 2
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\noindent Some text afterward

\end{document}
```

As a discussionary reference, see [Why is my `tabular` wider than the sum of its columns’ widths?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116917/5764).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As curiosity, why did you add the extra `\bigskip`s?

Comment: @XuWang: I just wanted to separate the contents.