# How can I prevent the first item in a table from being indented without affecting spacing?

Tags: tables, spacing, indentation

I have a table I am using for some headings. I would like the first entry in the table to not be indented, while being able to maintain the space between the first and seconds table items.

[image]

The latex code for my document:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 0.664cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{15cm} p{4cm}}
    \textbf{Company name} - position & 01/0001 - 12/2999
\end{tabular}\\
Just some random filler text

\end{document}
```

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205086/do-not-indent-a-tabular), which works but I have not been able to make it work while maintaining the spacing as I have it currently.

Is there a way?

Comment: I'm not seeing the need for a table.  It seems like `\noindent\textbf{Company name} - position\hfill01/0001 - 12/2999\\` would do the job, and be more semantic as well (and use `\makebox` or `\parbox` if you truly need the widths).

Comment: Try `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%` preferably in a group or environment.

Comment: @Teepeemm Is there something negative about using a table?

Comment: It's similar to the idea that using `<table>` tags is bad in html if you're only doing it for layout purposes.  A table should be for data in a tabular format, otherwise you're mixing styling and content.  (There's also a house of cards phenomena - the more commands you add in to try to make something work, the more likely something will go wrong.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `@{}` in before the first `p` column to remove the side bearing in the tabular. All columns has a `\tabcolsep` white space at each side. `@{}` remove the space between columns. You can do the same in the last column, to move right aligned (or justified) text in a column to the right margin.

The package [fullpage](https://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) is unnecessary when you use [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), and in addition, [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is a modern, flexible and much better package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}   %% Remove this line
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\usepackage[
top    = 0.608cm,
bottom = 0.664cm,
left   = 1.20cm,
right  = 1.10cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{15cm} p{4cm}}
    \textbf{Company name} - position & 01/0001 - 12/2999
\end{tabular}\\
Just some random filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange, I thought I had tried that. It worked though, thank you!

Comment: @JakeRankin See additional comment regarding `fullpage`.

Comment: Ah, noted, thank you.